# Angular: view does not updated after service response

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular (angular 14) and I try to create a simple to do app.

I have this component for todo list

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceListService } from '../services/service-list.service';
import { faEdit, faTrash, faCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.less']
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit  {


  // icons
  faEdit = faEdit;
  faTrash = faTrash;
  faCheck = faCheck;

  list: any = [];
  isFilterApplied = false;
  categoryValue = '';
  statusValue = '';
  constructor(private service:ServiceListService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private _ngzone: NgZone ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.FetchListFunction(this.categoryValue, this.statusValue, this.isFilterApplied);
  }

  FetchListFunction(categoryValue: string, statusValue: string, isFilterApplied: boolean){
    if (!isFilterApplied) {
      this.service.getList()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this._ngzone.run(() => { 
          this.list = response;
          this.cd.detectChanges();
          });
      });
    } else { 
      this.service.filterApplied(categoryValue, statusValue)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this._ngzone.run(() => { 
          this.list = response;
          this.cd.detectChanges();
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I create a **service for fetch list**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ServiceListService {
  isFilterEnabled = false;
  domain = 'http://localhost';
  url = this.domain + '/todocrud/api/fetchList.php';

 
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getList(){ // <= this run on first load when none filters applied
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url);
  }

  filterApplied(category: string, status: string){ // <= this run when any filter applied
    this.url = this.domain + `/todocrud/api/fetchList.php?status=${status}&category=${category}`;
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

And this is **filter component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceCategoriesService } from '../services/service-categories.service';
import { ListComponent } from '../list/list.component';
import { faList as faList } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filters',
  templateUrl: './filters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filters.component.less']
})
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {
  // icons
  faList = faList;


  categories:any;
  list:any;
  constructor(private serviceCategories:ServiceCategoriesService, private comp: ListComponent) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceCategories.getCategories()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.categories = response;
      });
  }

  statusValue = '';
  categoryValue = '';
  isFilterApplied: boolean = false;

  
  clickFilter(e: any){
    this.isFilterApplied = true;
    if (e.srcElement.parentElement.classList.contains('category')) {
      this.categoryValue = e.target.innerHTML;
    } else {
      var selectedStatus = e.target.innerHTML;
      if (selectedStatus === 'Completed') {
        this.statusValue = 'true';
      } else {
        this.statusValue = 'false';
      }
    }
    // console.log('Category:' + categoryValue) // selected category
    // console.log('Status:' + this.statusValue) // selected status
    this.comp.FetchListFunction(this.categoryValue, this.statusValue, this.isFilterApplied);
  }

}
```

Also this is **html for list**

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list " class="item {{ item.status }}">
        <div class="content" >
            <h6 class="header">{{item.id }}. {{ item.title }}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <span class="action-icon edit"><span class="icon"><fa-icon [icon]="faEdit"></fa-icon></span></span>
            <span class="action-icon delete"><span class="icon"><fa-icon [icon]="faTrash"></fa-icon></span></span>
            <span class="action-icon complete"><span class="icon"><fa-icon [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is html for **filters**

```
<div class="filters">
    <div class="FilterTitle">
        <span><span class="icon"><fa-icon [icon]="faList"></fa-icon></span>Filters: </span>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-holder">
        <mat-form-field class="filter status" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Status</mat-label>
            <mat-select name="status">
              <mat-option value="completed" class="status" (click)="clickFilter($event)">Completed</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="uncompleted" class="status" (click)="clickFilter($event)">Uncompleted</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="filter category" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
            <mat-select name="categories">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let item of categories" class="category" [value]="item" (click)="clickFilter($event)">{{item.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="filter-item clear-filter">
            <button mat-raised-button>Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Json response example**

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Venenatis lectus magna",
        "description": "gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et",
        "status": "in-progress",
        "completed": false,
        "category": "Movies to watch"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "title": "test",
        "description": "test description",
        "status": "in-progress",
        "completed": false,
        "category": "Movies to watch"
    }
]
```

On load (when page loaded first time) the list working perfectly, but when i change filters i see (from network) that response of my service is ok and i retrieve right data, but view of list does not change, i steel see list with all items.

I try to fix my problem with ngZone and ChangeDetector but it steel not working.

Where is the problem? How to update my view with new data from response?

Comment: try to use async pipe on html side

Comment: If there is no relation between components, i would recommend using data sharing like BehaviorSubject in service

Comment: Use subject or behaviour Subject. Calling components instance directly is not a good way of sharing data.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, i used behaviour Subject and it is work perfectly now!